# How to structure source control repository for a platform with iOS, Android, Web apps and Java backend?

Tags: java, android, ios, git, version-control

There is a back-end service written in Java and there is a web app, Android app and iOS app that serve the service.

Any typical SaaS product will fit this bill.

I am looking for best practices and guidelines so that I don't have to move code around and maximize the code to be modular.

Do you put code for each app in separate source control repositories or do they live in a single repository?

What is the usual practice?

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: Added specific question details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you put code for each app in separate source control repositories or do they live in a single repository?
>
> What is the usual practice?

They should be in a single repository each.

You can use `submodules` for this purpose.

Submodule is a project inside project. The benefits of submodules is that it will allow you to use shared resources for the IOS & Anndroid by sharing the same folders.

[Git-Tools-Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)
[git-tip-of-week-git-submodules](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-git-submodules.html)

[image]

Comment: Anyway that means to have separate repositories for each platform, right? So if you are building iOS, Android and Backend you have to create 4 repos and the Main one will include other 3 as submodules. Is this what you propose?